# Optional modules in Magento 2 CE?

Tags: magento2, extensions

Due to problems encountered and/or bugs, I have already learned that things like 'dotmailer' and 'facebook store' which appear to be built into the v2.2.2 magento CE we installed aren't necessary if you don't plan to use them.  I'm wondering if there are any other modules in that list that might be disabled if not used? (such as the amazon modules, tax modules - we use taxjar, specific shipping modules - we're using Magento_shipping now with temando, etc.)
I'm just wondering if there are any that can be turned off without 'breaking' magento as a whole.